# How to cite image source using bibtex?

Tags: graphics, bibtex

I did't find dedicated image entry in biblatex.
Please help.
One way is using @misc,
Is there a better option.

I will be using apalike bibliography.

Comment: The `@misc` entry type is indeed the "catch-all" type.